# How to put date from sql into tableview into javafx?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, javafx

I have a tableview that I am trying to populate from a query I created using a sql database. One of the columns holds a date value and when I run the program I am getting an error that says "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name AppointmentDate is not valid." Here is some of my code.

HoustonAppointments.java

```
    //Set variable    
    java.util.Date AppointmentDate;

    //Constructor
    public HoustonAppointments(Date appointmentDate) {
        AppointmentDate = appointmentDate;
    }

    //Getter and setter
    public java.util.Date getAppointmentDate() {
        return AppointmentDate;
    }
    public void setAppointmentDate(java.util.Date appointmentDate) {
        AppointmentDate = appointmentDate;
    }
```

Controller class

```
    public class HoustonAppointmentsController implements Initializable {

        //Connect control from FXML
        @FXML TableColumn<HoustonAppointments, Date> AppointmentDate;

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
            //Set cell value factory
            AppointmentDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("AppointmentDate"));

            //Query function
            try{

            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName, 
            City.CityName, Appointments.AppointmentDate as 'Appointment Date'\n" +
                    "FROM Orders INNER JOIN\n" +
                    "Customer ON Orders.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID INNER JOIN\n" +
                    "ShootLocation ON Orders.LocationID = ShootLocation.LocationID INNER JOIN\n" +
                    "City INNER JOIN\n" +
                    "CityState ON City.CityID = CityState.CityID ON ShootLocation.CityStateID = 
           CityState.CityStateID INNER JOIN\n" +
                    "Appointments ON Customer.CustomerID = Appointments.CustomerID AND 
           ShootLocation.LocationID = Appointments.LocationID\n" +
                    "Where CityName = 'Houston'\n" +
                    "Order by Appointments.AppointmentDate desc");

            while(rs.next()){
                shootsObservableList.add(new HoustonAppointments(rs.getDate("AppointmentDate")));
            }

            conn.close();
            statement.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        houstonShootsTableView.setItems(shootsObservableList);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have a space in the `as` clause. The column will be named `Appointment Date`, not `AppointmentDate`.

Comment: Oh, I was under the assumption that since it is an alias I would still use the actual column name. I will try this though

Comment: This worked. Thanks @RealSkeptic

Comment: An alias in this context means "Here is an expression, calculate it and give it this name so I can access the result". It's just a special case that your expression is actually a single column name. Thus your original column name is not actually one of the columns in this select statement, it's just a basis for the calculation of one of the columns.